# GM_deleteValue other script

Tags: jquery, greasemonkey

In greasemonkey I want to delete a value of another script.

I have :

**Script name:** Facebook login

```
extensions.greasemonkey.scriptvals.https://www.facebook.com/*/Facebook login.password;
extensions.greasemonkey.scriptvals.https://www.facebook.com/*/Facebook login.username;
```

In another script named : Facebook delete I want to delete the username and password form the facebook login script with

```
GM_deleteValue
```

Is this possible and if it is how can I do it?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. One script cannot see the values stored by a different script, using `GM_setValue()`.  Stored values are segregated by namespace and script name and cross referencing is not permitted, not even by `GM_deleteValue()`.

This is a security feature.  You'll have to merge the two scripts.
Note that there are already [frameworks to handle this kind of login info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15269327/331508) in/for a Greasemonkey script.