# Get client information from a Greasemonkey script (local machine name, Firefox profile)

Tags: javascript, security, greasemonkey

I've searched around here and there is a couple threads on it; but with normal javascript it seems near impossible to get the local machine name in Firefox.

I couldn't get a clear answer but would assume the same applies to Greasemonkey scripts too?

This GM script will run only on my browsers; is there any special settings or privileges I could give it or Firefox to get the local machine name?

Second question:

Is it possible to get which Firefox profile I'm running under?

Comment: The hostname is readily available (`location.hostname`). Do you really mean the local PC name?

Comment: yes, local client's hostname.

Answer (score 0):

No.  You cannot read the local machine name, nor Firefox profile name, nor Firefox profile directory using javascript or Greasemonkey.

If you could access this information, it would be *at least* [a "sec-moderate" security breach](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Security_Severity_Ratings).  So, if you figure out a hack for this, let us know immediately, so we can shut you down. ;)

Comment: ok, good to know.  Is there any way I can make my clients unique?  My script only runs on my browsers.  I process some of our intranet and need to find a unique ID per client so can monitor them.  For example, say I log "client having problems".... I send that up to a central web server; but hard to say which client is having problems as there is more than one (profile) per IP.  I would assume Environment Vars are off limits too?

Comment: You can give each user a unique ID that they must type in the first time your script runs, then store that ID using `GM_setValue()`.  The script logic is *similar* to [this problem](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15269327/331508).

Comment: I understand of course that this would be a security breach if ANY script from the web could do it. However, a Greasemonkey script is installed on purpose by a user, much like a browser extension. There are legitimate scenarios in which browser extensions need to have access to things normally not available to web scripts. So, why is it a security breach if a Greasemonkey script reads the local machine name?