# Autologin script won't work

Tags: greasemonkey, autologin, tampermonkey

I cannot get my autologin Tampermonkey script to work on a webpage.

This is the source of the page:

```
<p>
    <label for="username" style="opacity: 1;">Gebruikersnaam</label>
    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" autocomplete="off" autofocus="">
</p>
<p>
    <label for="password">Wachtwoord</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" autocomplete="off">
</p>
<button id="authLeftPaneLoginButton" class="smscButton">
    Aanmelden
</button>
```

A translation for some words:
Gebruikersnaam means username
Wachtwoord means password
Aanmelden means login

Here is the tampermonkey code I am using:

```
waitForKeyElements('document.getElementById("username")', enterUsername())
function enterUsername (jNode) { 
    $("#username").val("username_here"); 
} 
$("#password").val("password_here");
```

Comment: Could you post your auto login code please?

Comment: waitForKeyElements('document.getElementById("username")', enterUsername())

function enterUsername (jNode) {
$("#username").val("username_here");
}
$("#password").val("password_here");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. That is not how to use `waitForKeyElements()`. The first parameter needs to be a [jQuery selector](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).
2. You need to wait for *both* the username and password.
3. Don't hardcode credentials in a script!!  That is a dangerously bad practice.  You ***will*** get pwned.

To fix your immediate problem, the code would be like this:

```
waitForKeyElements ('#username', enterUsername);
waitForKeyElements ('#password', enterPassword);

function enterUsername (jNode) { 
    jNode.val ("username_here"); 
} 

function enterPassword (jNode) { 
    jNode.val ("password_here"); 
}
```

**But, to avoid certain doom, use [a login framework that protects your credentials](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15269327/331508).**

Comment: So then i append this script at the end of the login framework and change "username_here" and "password_here" to usr and pword? or do i have to use one of the functions to decrypt them first?

Comment: Yes, just make those first 2 changes and also change the `@include` to match your site.  Decryption is handled automatically by that framework.