# Flush tampermonkey changes

Tags: tampermonkey

I am trying to create a Tampermonkey script to automatically fill a login form with my username and password and then I would like to click the login button. However, with the code below, it appears to wait the three seconds, and THEN it fills the text into the boxes. How can I "flush" the changes so that they appear before the wait time occurs?

Thanks!

```
(function() {
    'use strict';
     function wait(ms){
           var start = new Date().getTime();
           var end = start;
           while(end < start + ms) {
                end = new Date().getTime();
           }
     }
     window.onbeforeunload = function (){
     return "Leaving page...";
     }
     $(document).ready(function() {
         document.getElementById("username").value = "userValue";
         document.getElementById("password").value = "passwordValue";
         wait(3000);
         document.getElementsByClassName("btn-large").click();
     });
})();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That `wait` function is locking up the browser tab (and probably the browser, and potentially the whole computer). Don't code like that!

Also:

1. `(function() {...` is completely superfluous in a Tampermonkey script.
2. `$(document).ready(function()...` is not helpful except in rare cases that do not apply here.
3. [Lots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15268645/storing-user-login-password-input-in-a-greasemonkey-script-on-install),   [lots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15048223/choosing-and-activating-the-right-controls-on-an-ajax-driven-site)   [more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-do-queryselectorall-getelementsbyclassname-and-other-getelementsby-method), etc...

Here's that code refactored:

```js
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
    return "Leaving page...";
}
//-- Hacker easter egg!  See linked questions.
document.getElementById ("username").value = "userValue";
document.getElementById ("password").value = "passwordValue";

setTimeout (clickBtnAfterDelay, 3000);

function () {
    //-- Brittle!  See linked questions.
    document.getElementsByClassName ("btn-large")[0].click ();
}
```

Comment: Ok, thanks! Sorry about the code; I’m not a JavaScript guy.

Comment: Thanks are good, but did you [find the post useful](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up)?  Do you agree that it [solves the issue outlined  in the question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)?  (Based on the information given at the time; it does.)

Comment: Sorry - totally missed accepting the answer! That's fixed now.