# How to fix button not showing up in TamperMonkey script

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

I am trying to adapt an existing TamperMonkey Script to create a dropdown based login button on an existing page.

I tested the working script which I found online on it's original URL (facebook.com) and the button shows up just fine.

When I adapt the @include to my URL and adjust the locator ID's in the script to match the ones in my own page, the script no longer displays the dropdown button.

And I need a little help figuring out why.

The original code looks like this and works on facebook.com:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        facebook login
// @namespace   http://123.123
// @include     https://www.facebook.com/*
// @version     1
// @require     http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.7.2.js
// @require     http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js
// @resource    bt http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css
// @resource    bt-theme http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css
// @grant       GM_addStyle
// @grant       GM_getResourceText
// ==/UserScript==
(function() {
    if ($('#login_form').length <= 0) {
        console.log('No login_form');
        return;
    }

    GM_addStyle(GM_getResourceText("bt"));
    GM_addStyle(GM_getResourceText ("bt-theme"));
    GM_addStyle("#menu1 a {text-align: left}");
    var $loginbutton = $('#loginbutton');
    var menu = '<span class="dropdown btn btn-primary" style="padding: 2px; margin: 0 0 0 5px;">' +
               '<a id="drop4" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" style="color: #FFF">帳號 ' +
               '<b class="caret"></b>' +
               '</a>' +
               '<ul id="menu1" class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="drop4" role="menu">' +
               '<li>' +
               '<a href="#" role="menuitem">kaoyenchi</a>' +
               '</li>' +
               '<li>' +
               '<a href="#" role="menuitem">tcyc</a>' +
               '</li>' +
               '<li>' +
               '<a href="#" role="menuitem">fcwu</a>' +
               '</li>' +
               '</ul>' +
               '</span>'
    $loginbutton.parent().append(menu);
    var accounts = {};
    accounts['fcwu'] = ['', ''];
    accounts['kaoyenchi'] = ['', ''];
    accounts['tcyc'] = ['', ''];
    accounts['timy'] = ['', ''];
    $('#menu1 a').click(function() {
        name = $(this).text()
        $('#email').attr('value', accounts[name][0]);
        $('#pass').attr('value', accounts[name][1]);
        $('#login_form').submit();
    });

})();
```

And the code looks like this after my changes and no longer works:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Login-o-Tron WIP
// @namespace   http://123.123
// @include     http://myurl.com/*
// @version     1
// @require     http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.7.2.js
// @require     http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js
// @resource    bt http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css
// @resource    bt-theme http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css
// @grant       GM_addStyle
// @grant       GM_getResourceText
// ==/UserScript==
(function() {

    GM_addStyle(GM_getResourceText("bt"));
    GM_addStyle(GM_getResourceText ("bt-theme"));
    GM_addStyle("#menu1 a {text-align: left}");
    var $loginbutton = $('#loginbutton');
    var menu = '<span class="dropdown btn btn-primary" style="padding: 2px; margin: 0 0 0 5px;">' +
               '<a id="drop4" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" style="color: #FFF">Login-o-Tron ' +
               '<b class="caret"></b>' +
               '</a>' +
               '<ul id="menu1" class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="drop4" role="menu">' +
               '<li>' +
               '<a href="#" role="menuitem">kaoyenchi</a>' +
               '</li>' +
               '<li>' +
               '<a href="#" role="menuitem">tcyc</a>' +
               '</li>' +
               '<li>' +
               '<a href="#" role="menuitem">fcwu</a>' +
               '</li>' +
               '</ul>' +
               '</span>'
    $loginbutton.parent().append(menu);
    var accounts = {};
    accounts['fcwu'] = ['', ''];
    accounts['kaoyenchi'] = ['', ''];
    accounts['tcyc'] = ['', ''];
    accounts['timy'] = ['', ''];
    $('#menu1 a').click(function() {
        name = $(this).text()
        $('#username').attr('value', accounts[name][0]);
        $('#password').attr('value', accounts[name][1]);
        $('#loginButton').submit();
    });

})();
```

I made sure the locators are correct, and I tried keeping and losing the initial if statement, but it doesn't seem to affect the outcome.

I do see the font of my page changing when the script loads, so the CSS is loaded, but the dropdown button I am expecting to show, never shows up.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't say if there where any errors in the console, but the problem is *probably* that the `#loginbutton` node is added by javascript -- which means it would appear after your script ran.

Also, `menu1` and `drop4` are pretty generic.  There is a chance that they may already be used, causing id conflict.  Use something less common and more descriptive (except that `drop4` does not seem to be needed at all).

One way around the delay problem is to use something like `waitForKeyElements` as shown below.

**Important:**

1. If you put passwords in a text file/record like that, it's only a matter of time before those accounts get hacked/pwned.
2. The smart thing to do is to use a password manager like *LastPass*, *KeePass*, etc.
3. Failing that, at least use [an encryption framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15268645/storing-user-login-password-input-in-a-greasemonkey-script-on-install) to make it noticeably harder for bad guys to get the account credentials.

**Revised script:**

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Login-o-Tron WIP
// @include     http://myurl.com/*
// @require     http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.7.2.js
// @require     http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js
// @require     https://gist.github.com/raw/2625891/waitForKeyElements.js
// @resource    bt http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css
// @resource    bt-theme http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css
// @grant       GM_addStyle
// @grant       GM_getResourceText
// ==/UserScript==
/* global $, waitForKeyElements */
/* eslint-disable no-multi-spaces, dot-notation */

GM_addStyle (GM_getResourceText("bt") );
GM_addStyle (GM_getResourceText ("bt-theme") );
GM_addStyle ("#TM_accmenu a {text-align: left;}");

waitForKeyElements ("#loginbutton", addAccountsDropdown);

const accounts          = {};
accounts['fcwu']        = ['One',   'should'];
accounts['kaoyenchi']   = ['have',  'a'];
accounts['tcyc']        = ['bad',   'feeling'];
accounts['timy']        = ['about', 'this.'];

function addAccountsDropdown (jNode) {
    var jMenu = $( `
        <span class="dropdown btn btn-primary" style="padding: 2px; margin: 0 0 0 5px;">
            <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" style="color: #FFF">Login-o-Tron
                <b class="caret"></b>
            </a>
            <ul id="TM_accmenu" class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="drop4" role="menu"></ul>
        </span>
    ` );
    var zList = jMenu.find ("#TM_accmenu");
    for (let acntName in accounts) {
        zList.append (`<li><a href="#" role="menuitem">${acntName}</a></li>`);
    }

    jNode.parent ().append (jMenu);
    $('#TM_accmenu a').click (function () {
        var acntName = $(this).text ()
        $('#username').attr ('value', accounts[acntName][0]);
        $('#password').attr ('value', accounts[acntName][1]);
        $('#loginButton').submit ();
    } );
}
```

Comment: I have tried adding this script to my page using TamperMonkey, but the dropdown still does not show up.

My HTML looks as follows:

https://pastebin.com/gzG6DhqJ